# NestJS Application build on Heroku crashes because of TypeOrmModule with no precise error message

Tags: typescript, heroku, nestjs

I have a working application built on NestJS, which is deployed on a Heroku server. It used to work, until recently every build I do crashes with no good reason. I did some trials, and discovered that the app works when the `TypeOrmModule` is not included in the `AppModule` imports, But obviously it is unusable without the database. Here is how the `AppModule` config looks like:

```js
const databaseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(databaseUrl ? {
      type: 'postgres',
      url: databaseUrl,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
   } : {
      // configuration for local development
   }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have checked and the `databaseUrl` is being correctly loaded from the environment URL. This is not a stripped showcase example, this is literally what I deploy to Heroku - I have removed all other modules to understand where the problem was coming from.  If I remove the `TypeOrmModule` now the app **will not** crash. Here is the unhelpful log that heroku provides me upon crash:

> 07/08/2020, 12:09:13 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
> 2020-07-08T12:09:13.300817+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 23
> 07/08/2020, 12:09:13 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +76ms
> 2020-07-08T12:09:13.301462+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 23
> 07/08/2020, 12:09:13 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
> 2020-07-08T12:09:13.416093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
> 2020-07-08T12:09:13.463362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
> 2020-07-08T12:09:13.463362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

The build before the app start **has been successful** indicated in the same log. I have been truly at a loss here for more than a month.

Comment: Is there any chance you can share a reproduction? A link to your repo or something like that?

Comment: I could try, but in reality my app is just basic generated Nest app + imported TypeOrmModule. Even without the entities it crashes. So I think maybe something in the server config is not right, but obviously I cannot share credentials. So I am at a loss here.

Comment: Have you tried connect to that database from local machine? Maybe there is something wrong in connection url string?

Comment: "status 0" means no error, seems like your process simply exits. Are you correctly calling `app.listen(process.env.PORT)`? You should post your entire setup, package.json, bootstrap function, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one in your **main.ts** to get log for such case:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
   Logger.warn(err, 'LOGGER', false);
});
```

If not enough, you may add other events for debugging by referencing here:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_events

And please check your **tsconfig.json** file If you have **any migrations** module and target should be like this one:

```
"target": "es2015",
"module": "CommonJS",
```

*And one last thing:* Make sure your **database** name matches with TypeORM config